# Would Tabata be any good on a stationary bike?

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, bicycling, tabata

I cycle most evenings when I get home from work.
I read about Tabata on here and wondered if it would be any good for me?
Maybe cut my total time down to 30 minutes, 5 mins warm up, 2 mins Tabata, 5 mins cool-down?
I'm trying to lose fat, at a decent rate. I eat well, just want to lose it quicker!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fine to use a stationary bike for Tabata-style interval training. Much of [Tabata's](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9139179) [research](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8897392) was on stationary bikes.

The protocol [prescribes](http://www.brianmac.co.uk/tabata.htm) 4 minutes total of intense intervals:

> The whole session last 14 minutes and comprises of a 5 minute warm up, 4 minutes of intense exercise and a 5 minute cool down. The 4 minutes of intense exercise comprises of 8 repeats of 20 seconds of maximum effort work of your selected exercise followed by a recovery of 10 seconds.

If you're reasonably fit already, doing absolutely all-out effort for twenty seconds eight times should be exhausting.

Comment: Bad typing on my count there, I meant 2 minutes as I'm not the fittest yet. 
But I'm thinking go for the 4 minutes anyway now, never gonna get there otherwise!
Thanks Dave.

Comment: @Saveyourself91 I started my Tabata with 6 rounds of effort (3 mins), but progressed within a couple of weeks to the full 8. You are correct, your last few rounds will probably be very bad but you can't improve if you don't do 'em.

Comment: Thanks VPeric. I'm going to shoot the full 8 from the off. If I can't do it I'll take it down to 6 for a week then tr again.

Comment: I'm looking to start tabata on a stationary bike also. What sort of gear should I be looking at starting on? Is the idea to have the bike on an 'easier' gear so that during the high-output 20 seconds I should be peddling very quickly or should I be looking to use a difficult gear on which during the 20 seconds I am struggling to turn the wheels?

Comment: @Phizzy You should post that as its own question! :D I'd say it should be somewhere in the middle. Experiment to find which setting makes it possible to exert the most energy as fast as possible.